# Python - copy files of one type

Tags: python, copy

I want to copy all files from folderA ("\192.168.2.xxx\shareA") of the type "*.ts" to folderB ("\192.168.2.yyy\shareB").

```
src = "\\\\192.168.2.xxx\\Harddisk\\*.ts"
dst = "\\\\192.168.2.yyy\\video"
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

This doesn't really work. It gives me that error:

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\\\\192.168.2.115\\Harddisk\\*.ts'
```

Why is he writing the path with "\\"? If I print `src` it gives me `\\192.168.2.115\Harddisk\*.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutil.copyfile(src, dst)` copies the contents of a single file, so it is looking for the `*.ts` filename. The path is written with `'\\'` because it is an escape character; it is how you write the `\` character. You can use the glob module to do Unix style pathname pattern expansion, though. This script should work if you run it from the directory containing `192.168.2.xxx` and `192.168.2.yyy`.

```
import glob, shutil

for filename in glob.glob('192.168.2.xxx\\Harddisk\\*.ts'):
  shutil.copyfile(filename, '192.168.2.yyy\\video\\' + filename)
```

Comment: I tried to copy one explicit file with a corerct name that exists. That doesn't work either. And which function I have to use for more then one file?

Comment: copyfile starts its path in the directory from which the program is executed. Try running the program from the directory containing 192.168.2.xxx and 192.168.2.yyy.